# failed to lazily initialize a collection of role... could not initialize proxy - no Session - @Transactional not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have an issue with learning Hibernate OneToMany.
My test code hast a Studend who has many Books.

```
@OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "student",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE}
    )
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
```

As expected when I tried to read a Student and access books, I got mentioned in title error, because default behavion in OneToMany is LAZY.

```
@Transactional
    private void testowy(StudentRepository studentRepository){
        studentRepository.findById(4L).ifPresent(
                s -> {

                    System.out.println(s);

                    s.addBook(new Book(LocalDateTime.now(),"pozycja1"));

                    studentRepository.save(s);
                }
        );
    }
```

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.demo.Student.books, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

But as you can see, I googled/stacoverflowed a little and found that if I use @Transactional annotation, session should not be broken. But it doesn't working for me.

I also tried property "enable_lazy_load_no_trans = true" and it is also not fixing an issue, but I don't know if this is a direction which I want to go...

How can I fix this error, what am I doing wrong with @Transactional annotation? (from import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;)

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.demo.Student.books, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

**EDIT**:
Regarding to proposition to change private to public, it did not help.

```
@Transactional
    public void testowy(StudentRepository studentRepository){
        System.out.println("-------before-----------");
        studentRepository.findById(4L).ifPresent(
                s -> {

                    System.out.println("------------------");
                        System.out.println(s);
                    System.out.println("------------------");

                    System.out.println("-------add-----------");
                    s.addBook(new Book(LocalDateTime.now(),"pozycja1"));
                    System.out.println("---------save---------");
                    studentRepository.save(s);
                }
        );
    }
```

Did not help:

```
-------before-----------
Hibernate: 
    select
        student0_.id as id1_2_0_,
        student0_.age as age2_2_0_,
        student0_.email as email3_2_0_,
        student0_.first_name as first_na4_2_0_,
        student0_.last_name as last_nam5_2_0_,
        studentidc1_.id as id1_3_1_,
        studentidc1_.card_number as card_num2_3_1_,
        studentidc1_.student_id as student_3_3_1_ 
    from
        student student0_ 
    left outer join
        student_id_card studentidc1_ 
            on student0_.id=studentidc1_.student_id 
    where
        student0_.id=?
------------------
2021-06-02 20:19:06,148  INFO  [        main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 
2021-06-02 20:19:06,170  ERROR [        main] o.springframework.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:807)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:788)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298)
    at com.example.demo.Application.main(Application.java:20)
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.demo.Student.books, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:621)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    at com.example.demo.Student.toString(Student.java:144)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3365)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:1047)
    at com.example.demo.Application.lambda$testowy$1(Application.java:60)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)
    at com.example.demo.Application.testowy(Application.java:56)
    at com.example.demo.Application.lambda$commandLineRunner$0(Application.java:39)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:804)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

Without additional configuration Spring AOP does not work on private methods, so change it to public

```
@Transactional
public void testowy(StudentRepository studentRepository){
```

Comment: And obviosuly it is insude a @Component body right?

Comment: I updated main topic, making method public did not help.

What do you mean @Component? Where it should be putted?

Comment: On the class you are running your code in

Comment: I am running this code in main class with 
@SpringBootApplication annotation
I don't know if "@Component" is correct for this class, but I can try.

Comment: Or you mean I MUST move this method to different class than main SpringBoot class?